# how to remove code duplications in this code?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, c99, code-duplication

I am a new C99 programmer and want the help of the community on this one.

I wrote the following function which receives two pointers for a node (Or simply Node) and a pointer to a pointer to node (Or *Node) an merges them together into one sorted Node.

**This is Given:**

```
typedef struct node_t {
    int x;
    struct node_t *next;
} *Node;

typedef enum {
    SUCCESS = 0,MEMORY_ERROR, EMPTY_LIST, UNSORTED_LIST, NULL_ARGUMENT,
} ErrorCode;

int getListLength(Node list);

bool isListSorted(Node list);
```

**This is the code I wrote:**

```
ErrorCode mergeSortedLists(Node list1, Node list2, Node *merged_out)
{
    if (merged_out==NULL)
        return NULL_ARGUMENT;
    if (list1==NULL || list2==NULL)
        return EMPTY_LIST;
    if (!isListSorted(list1) || !isListSorted(list2))
        return UNSORTED_LIST;
    Node ptr=*merged_out;
    int list1_len=getListLength(list1),list2_len=getListLength(list2);
    for (int i=0;i<list1_len+list2_len;i++)
    {
        int min=0;
        if (list1!=NULL && (list2==NULL || (list2!=NULL && list1->x<=list2->x))){
            min = list1->x;
            list1=list1->next;
        }
        else{
            min=list2->x;
            list2=list2->next;
        }
        ptr->x=min;
        if (i==list1_len+list2_len-1){
            ptr->next=NULL;//The next for the last Node should be Null
            continue;
        }
        ptr->next=malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
        if (ptr->next==NULL){
            //We should Free all previosly allocated memory
            //except for the first node since it was not allocated via malloc
            return MEMORY_ERROR;
        }
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
    ptr=NULL;
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

But after reviewing my code I was told it has a lot of code duplications (more precisely inside he for loop) which should be corrected by using external functions, do u notice any code duplications? and how to fix that, any ideas?

Comment: Here's a better place to ask this question : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: the forum there doesn't seem that active, plus for some reason I get an error

Comment: 1) Why do you return a *copy* of the merged lists? 2) Why don't you return the result as a return value , avoiding a pointer to pointer, or a dummy head node such as in your case? 3) why do you use the list lengthts, you are already checking for the NULL pointers ?

Comment: A function that re-arranges two lists by merging them shouldn't allocate memory -- there are no new nodes, after all. I don't think that passing `NULL` as any of the lists should be an error; that case could be handled by the function easily. There's no need to determine the length of the lists beforehand, you can control your loop entirely by testing the lists for `NULL`.

Comment: @wildplasser I can't change the function's signature

Comment: @MOehm right, but they gave us the length function to help

Comment: The function's sigmature is terrible. BTW: since you remember the `x` value you dont need the `isListSorted()` function, either.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is more suited to Code Review.

Comment: @wildplasser how can I replace isListSorted() with x?

Comment: strongly suggest using `C18` rather than `C99`  as `C99` is 20 years out-of-date

Comment: the posted code does not compile! first, it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files.

Comment: the posted code does not link.  it is missing a `main()` function

Comment: regarding: `typedef struct node_t {
    int x;
    struct node_t *next;
} *Node;`   It is very poor programming practice to hide a pointer in a `typedef`

Comment: OT: Please follow the axiom:  *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) insert an appropriate space: inside parens, inside braces, inside brackets, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators